# Fieldset odd legend underline issue

Tags: css, border, legend, fieldset, underline

I have an issue with a fieldset tag: the legend is underlined for no reason. How can I remove the thin line below it?

Here is a screenshot that shows the problem, I have added a red background just to highlight the line under the legend "HEY"

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: post your code or fiddle for better help...

Comment: [Normally it doesn't have any underline](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/f8Lyrp88/1/), we need to see your code.

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LvnL3trc/

the line does not appear here, but it does on bootstrap...I have no clue

Comment: Well, then reproduce your issue on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) and add it to your post.

Comment: Bootply version: http://www.bootply.com/VYO9KSCU61
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap is adding a `border-bottom` to `legend`. You can remove it by adding `border: 0` to `legend`.

### [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/k5VtlwAZqS)

```
legend {
  border: 0;
}
```